# Dynamically created div doesn't show up

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to show a tooltip when a user clicks on a div element. I found [this](http://jsfiddle.net/HUG2Z/62/) fiddle where a dynamically created div is used, but it doesn't get shown when I click on it. What am I doing wrong here?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.somefield').click(showBox).mouseleave(hideBox);

    function showBox(e){
        $newDiv = $('<div></div>');
        $newDiv.addClass('tooltip');
        $newDiv.append('adfhadfhadfhadfh')
        $(newDiv).fadeIn().css(({ left:  e.pageX, top: e.pageY }));
    }

    function hideBox(){
        $('.tooltip').fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Comment: For starters, that fiddle is throwing a script error: *Uncaught ReferenceError: newDiv is not defined*

Comment: There is so much wrong this fiddle that I do not know where to start. Please clean up the fiddle (use the resource panel, get rid of jquery script in html, fix your jquery.

Comment: $(newDiv).fadeIn().css(({ left:  e.pageX, top: e.pageY })); you are using newDiv instead of $newDiv wihch is declared variable name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pkdrz/1/)

You are using jQuery to create a div then later you try wrap an in-existent object in a jQuery object. Change `$(newDiv)` to `$newDiv`.

It doesn't show up because you need to add it on the document, you can append to body

```
$newDiv.appendTo("body");
```

If you are fading in, the element must first be hidden

```
$newDiv.css("display", "none");
```

So the fixed code looks like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.somefield').click(showBox).mouseleave(hideBox);

    function showBox(e){
        var $newDiv = $('<div></div>');
        $newDiv.css("display", "none");
        $newDiv.addClass('tooltip');
        $newDiv.append('adfhadfhadfhadfh')
        $newDiv.appendTo("body");
        $newDiv.fadeIn().css(({ left:  e.pageX, top: e.pageY }));
    }

    function hideBox(){
        $('.tooltip').fadeOut();
    }
});
```

appart from the addition of `$newDiv.appendTo("body");` also mind the `var` in the declaration of `$newDiv`

Comment: Why not use jQuery's `hide()`? Also, stack the functions.

Comment: No reason. It could be used. I didn't stack to leave it familiar to the OP, so he can see the few changes I added.

Comment: Good enough reasons, though it could be useful to provide the alternative as well - so OP learns about it.

Answer (score 1):

You are not appending your div to any other element inside DOM.

```
var newDiv = $("<div>", {
        'class': "tooltip"   
    });

newDiv.appendTo($('body'));
$('.tooltip').fadeIn().css(({ left:  e.pageX, top: e.pageY }));
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to insert `$newDiv` somewhere in the dom. for example `$('body').append($newDiv)`

Moreover $newDiv is implicit global which it shouldn't be. use `var $newDiv = ...` instead.